# VB .NET Fit RichTextBox width according to line length

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox

I have a RichTextBox which shows a line of its text in every timer's tick.
I need to fit RichTextBox width with the length of each line (shrink or grow according to the viewed line length).
I tried : TextRenderer.MeasureText(RichTextBox.SelectedText, font) , but no result.
So, is there any way to:

1. shrink or grow richtextbox width to fit each line length, Or,
2. set each line length to fit the predefined richtextbox width?

Comment: Of course there was a result. Maybe it wasn't the result you wanted but there was a result. You need to provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem. What did you actually do, what actually happened and how did that differ from your expectations?

Comment: You know that a `RichTextBox` will wrap text automatically, right?